# description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling the request

Tags: java, jsp

I create a form to check BMI from user's input height and weight. But after run project it throw this error message:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
> An exception occurred processing [/views/web/checkBMI.jsp] at line [35]
>
> 32:                   String ChieuCao = request.getParameter("txtChieuCao");
> 33:                   String CanNang = request.getParameter("txtCanNang");
> 34:
> 35:                   double height = Double.parseDouble(ChieuCao);
> 36:                   double weight = Double.parseDouble(CanNang);
> 37:                   double BMI = weight/(height * height);
> 38:

And here is my file checkBMI.jsp

```html
    <div class="title">
        KIỂM TRA BMI CỦA BẠN
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Chiều cao:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtChieuCao" placeholder="Enter your height (m)!"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cân nặng:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtCanNang" placeholder="Enter your weight (kg)!"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Kết Quả BMI:</td>
                <td>
                <%
                String ChieuCao = request.getParameter("txtChieuCao");
                String CanNang = request.getParameter("txtCanNang");
                
                double height = Double.parseDouble(ChieuCao);
                double weight = Double.parseDouble(CanNang);
                double BMI = weight/(height * height);
                
                if (BMI < 18.5) {
                    out.println("BMI: " + BMI);
                    out.println("Bạn đang thiếu cân! Bạn nên có chế độ ăn phù hợp hơn!");
                }
                else if (18.5 <= BMI && BMI <= 24.9) {
                    out.println("BMI: " + BMI);
                    out.println("Bạn đang có thể trạng khỏe mạnh, bạn nên duy trì thể trạng này!");
                }
                else if (25 <= BMI && BMI <= 29.9) {
                    out.println("BMI: " + BMI);
                    out.println("Bạn đang thừa cân! Bạn nên có chế độ ăn phù hợp hơn!");
                }
                else {
                    out.println("BMI: " + BMI);
                    out.println("Bạn đang béo phì! Bạn nên có chế độ ăn phù hợp hơn!");
                }
                %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form action="#" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried the ways that I know, but it doesn't work. Please help me.

Comment: most likely smth is wrong with the input. Could you check what the value is you received from request for "ChieuCao" and "CanNang"

Comment: You didn't include a stacktrace for the internal error.  That means people have to **guess** what the cause of your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is caused by the Double.parseDouble method failing to parse the input as a valid number. A possible correction could be like that;

```
String ChieuCao = request.getParameter("txtChieuCao");
String CanNang = request.getParameter("txtCanNang");

if (ChieuCao == null || ChieuCao.isEmpty() || CanNang == null || CanNang.isEmpty()) {
    out.println("Please enter a valid height and weight!");
} else {
    double height = Double.parseDouble(ChieuCao);
    double weight = Double.parseDouble(CanNang);
    double BMI = weight/(height * height);

if (BMI < 18.5) {
    // output BMI results
} else if (18.5 <= BMI && BMI <= 24.9) {
    // output BMI results
} else if (25 <= BMI && BMI <= 29.9) {
    // output BMI results
} else {
    // output BMI results
}
}
```